# Using generic types with a Map typed with Enum keys in a subclass context

Tags: java, enums

I have the following structure with a parent class, several subclasses, and each of the subclasses has its own Enum with various keys. The parent class is required to have a map with keys characterized by the Enum, but the Enum type is abstract - it's determined by which subclass is being instantiated.

I would like to use generic types to require that the Enum type is from that specific class - so you can only add APPLE to Fruits and CELERY to Veggies and never vice versa. My application also requires any Food object to be able to query its possible types (like to say, print out all of the types that are possible, not just the types we have in the Map).

How can I use generic types to make that all work? I am getting the compiler error on the line with the EnumSet declaration `Uncompilable source code - type argument E is not within bounds of type-variable E`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sandbox {

    private static class Food<E extends Enum> {

        public Map<E, Integer> qty = new HashMap<>();
        public EnumSet<E> types = EnumSet.allOf(E);

    }

    private static class Fruit extends Food<Fruit.Type> {

        public static enum Type {
            APPLE,
            ORANGE
        }

    }

    private static class Veggie extends Food<Veggie.Type> {

        public static enum Type {
            CUCUMBER,
            CELERY
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Fruit mondays = new Fruit();
        mondays.qty.put(Fruit.Type.APPLE, 1);
        mondays.qty.put(Fruit.Type.ORANGE, 3);

        Veggie tuesdays = new Veggie();
        tuesdays.qty.put(Veggie.Type.CELERY, 10);

        mondays.qty.forEach((f, qty) -> System.out.println("Buying " + f + " in qty " + qty));
        tuesdays.qty.forEach((f, qty) -> System.out.println("Buying " + f + " in qty " + qty));

        mondays.types.forEach(System.out::print);

    }
}
```

Comment: There are various isues here. E is a type variable and can only be used where types are expected. The argument to a method (such as the `allOf` method of `EnumSet`) cannot be a type. You can't write `EnumSet.allOf(int)` either. It gets worse; given that erasure is a thing, you can't fix the typo - it is fundamentally impossible to make an enumset representing 'all values of this typevar'.

Comment: Second issue: It's `E extends Enum<E>`, not `E extends Enum`. That latter one involves raw types; you don't want that.

Comment: Fixing that `E extends Enum<E>` thing, I think your interactions with the `qty` field would then work fine. The `types` field is a much bigger issue. You can either resort to some fairly crazy hackery that adds all sorts of weird precondition requirements to your codebase, or, you just get rid of it (your example doesn't actually use this field), or, you demand that each class (e.g. `Fruit` and `Veggie`) takes care of this, or at least gives the Food constructor what it needs to init this, such as calling `super(Fruit.Type.class)`.

Comment: The interactions with qty don't even require generics, I was able to use a Map<Enum, Integer> just fine. But the class does really need to have access to Types, perhaps to check that every Fruit has been purchased and none are missing. What's the cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the fact that enums can implement interfaces, using an interface as the type constraint of `Food` instead of `Enum<>`. Then make `Food` abstract so that each specific food subtype can declare its enum type.

```java
    private static interface FoodType {}

    private static abstract class Food<T extends FoodType> {

        public Map<T, Integer> qty = new HashMap<>();

        protected abstract Set<T> getTypes();

    }

    private static class Fruit extends Food<Fruit.Type> {

        public static enum Type implements FoodType {
            APPLE,
            ORANGE
        }

        @Override
        protected Set<Type> getTypes() {
            return EnumSet.allOf(Type.class);
        }

    }

    private static class Veggie extends Food<Veggie.Type> {

        public static enum Type implements FoodType {
            CUCUMBER,
            CELERY
        }

        @Override
        protected Set<Type> getTypes() {
            return EnumSet.allOf(Type.class);
        }
    }
```

If you want be slightly more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and avoid implementing `getTypes()` in every concrete `Food` subclass, you can pass in the array of enum values in a protected constructor. Like this:

```java
    private static interface FoodType { }

    private static abstract class Food<T extends FoodType> {
        public Map<T, Integer> qty;
        public Set<T> types;

        protected Food(T[] types) {
            this.types = Set.of(types);
            this.qty = new HashMap<>();
        }

    }

    private static class Fruit extends Food<Fruit.Type> {

        protected Fruit() {
            super(Type.values());
        }

        public static enum Type implements FoodType {
            APPLE,
            ORANGE;
        }
    }

    private static class Veggie extends Food<Veggie.Type> {

        protected Veggie() {
            super(Type.values());
        }

        public static enum Type implements FoodType {
            CUCUMBER,
            CELERY
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow thank you. The DRY method does look nice and I will use this in my code